# VBA Text To Columns not fully applying 24hr format to time

Tags: excel, vba, time, text-to-column

Morning all,

I've got the below section of code which doesn't seem to want to convert the time element of column A into 24hr. The data is in original format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Every time after midday is being displayed in 12hr format i.e. 14:12 is shown as 02:12

(the deleting of rows and columns doesn't relate to the text to columns process but is included in the segment below)

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Rows("1:5").delete Shift:=xlUp
    .Range("F:F,N:N,O:O,P:P,S:S,U:U,V:V").delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    .Columns("B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Columns("B").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    .Columns("A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

I've got the third array segment to not display AM/PM in a third column.

EDIT: above code includes @PeterT suggestion of formatting newly inserted column B to HH:mm:ss - Unfortunately any time between 13:00:00 and 23:59:59 are still being converted to 01:00:00 and 11:59:59 , respectively.

EDIT: I've included better examples of what I'm struggling with.

This is how the workbook starts out:
[image]

And this is how the Text To Columns process in the VBA code changes the time format (it's showing as 01:17:52 when it should be 13:17:52):
[image]

I've had some really useful advice from members on another unrelated code question, I'm hoping for the same again :) I have searched and found similar questions but none resulted in the answer to fix this unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome MikeE! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Try adding `.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"` to your code to format the column for time in 24 hr format.

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue you're having is trying to work with date and time as text. I can't even tell whether your column 'A' is really in Date/Time format because the alignment is centered. If the data is **Text**, the alignment would be to the **Left**. If the data were in **Date/Time** format, the alignment would be **Right**. Once you figure that out, just copy the cells and change the format.

Comment: @PeterT - I'm afraid that didn't have any effect.

Comment: @NickAbbot column A is created as "Custom" (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)

Comment: Running your code against the data works for me, if you place the `.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"` after the `.TextToColumns` line.

Comment: @PeterT - i've inserted that bit of code as below but it's still turning 24hr entries into 12hr i.e 13:16:03 into 01:16:03
    `.Columns("A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        .Columns("B").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    End With`

Comment: In your original data, you only show `11:00` for the time. How is it shown for a time after 12:00?

Comment: Would help to use sample data which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: His data is totally **not** a Date/Time format. He's getting exactly what I get when I use his text for the date.

Comment: @PeterT if it's originally anything in between 12:00:00 and 12:59:59 it stays the same, no issues. If it's anything 13:00:00 to 23:59:59 it changes to 12hr so reads 01:00:00 to 11:59:59 instead.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams , I have an example but can't see where to add attachments when editing the post, any ideas?

Comment: @NickAbbot the workbook comes preformatted, when I press Ctrl+1 to view the formatting options on the data in column A (Date/Time) it's set to 'Custom' dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (there are seconds values recorded just now shown in this default format).

Comment: What the formatting is and how Excel(`.TextToColumns`) treats that data are two different things.

Comment: When I ran your code, with my suggested addition, I modified your data to include time values greater than 13:00 and it still worked to format the values. So I think there's something missing from your example data or code snippet that is preventing the time format to be set.

Comment: @PeterT I've edited my original post to show the code I'm using with your addition of the time format which isn't yielding the desired result. Also, I included images with a more precise example of what I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more "manual" but this worked fine for me:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, arr, r As Long, v
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Columns("B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
    ws.Range("B1").Value = "Time"
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    arr = rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(r, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            v = v * 1                 'coerce date to number
            arr(r, 1) = Int(v)        'Date only
            arr(r, 2) = v - arr(r, 1) 'Time only
        End If
    Next r
    rng.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'set required column formats
    rng.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    rng.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, this seems to work quite nicely instead of using the Text To Columns feature. I've tweaked it slightly by changing the number formats to m/d/yyyy and hh:mm:ss. Not sure why putting the date in that format results in what I'm after (UK/Euro format of dd/mm/yyyy) but it works so not going to question it!
You've got me thinking about tidying up the rest of the code now as I've been advised in another question to avoid using select and I can see you've done that when naming the cells "Date" and "Time", will try and replicate that throughout the rest of the code. Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't tell from your dates (month and day < 12) so I defaulted to my local date format.  Glad this is working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I can see the expanded sample data, I can see that the `TextToColumns` method is actually splitting the timestamp into ***three*** columns (not two). So that `06/10/2023 13:17` actually becomes:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/10/2023 | 1:17:00 | PM |

So now the trick is to combine columns B and C into a single time value and convert that.

Here is some example code to help with the conversion.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Rows("1:5").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Range("F:F,N:N,O:O,P:P,S:S,U:U,V:V").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Dim theDate As Date
            Dim theTime As Date
            Dim tokens() As String
            tokens = Split(.Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
            theDate = DateValue(tokens(0))
            theTime = TimeValue(tokens(1) & " " & tokens(2))
                    
            '--- put the values in their place
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = theDate
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = theTime
        Next i
        .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Columns("B").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I've used this in place of what I was using but unfortunately get a run time error '13': Type Mismatch at this section `theDate = DateValue(tokens(0))`
Any ideas what is causing that?

Comment: The code above works with the limited sample data you posted. I would suggest checking the value of `tokens(0)` when the run time error occurs to see why its value would cause the error. Then you can create an `If` statement to check for that value to prevent the error.